# Xamarin ADB0010: Deployment failed

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, deployment

Xamarin app working and deployable to earlier and later than this new device in question which is Android 7.1.2.
Direct installation from the app center / ADB install also works normally on this device.

Debugging, however, will fail with the following error.

- Checked that in the developer option that USB debugging is enabled.
- Tried to uninstall the app from Settings - App as well as `adb uninstall <package_name>`
- Tried deploying a minimal new project to the device, failed with the same result. So it's more likely that it's related to the system's setting?

```
Installing the API 28 platform framework.
10% ... 3072kb of 30156kb copied
20% ... 6080kb of 30156kb copied
30% ... 9088kb of 30156kb copied
40% ... 12096kb of 30156kb copied
50% ... 15104kb of 30156kb copied
60% ... 18112kb of 30156kb copied
70% ... 21120kb of 30156kb copied
80% ... 24128kb of 30156kb copied
90% ... 27200kb of 30156kb copied
100% ... 30156kb of 30156kb copied
ADB0010:  Deployment failed
Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: app_process: ro.boot.root property .Success

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass97_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__114.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<EnsureCorrectSharedRuntimes>d__111.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__110.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__108.MoveNext()
ADB0010: Mono.AndroidTools.InstallFailedException: Unexpected install output: app_process: ro.boot.root property .Success

   at Mono.AndroidTools.Internal.AdbOutputParsing.CheckInstallSuccess(String output, String packageName)
   at Mono.AndroidTools.AndroidDevice.<>c__DisplayClass97_0.<InstallPackage>b__0(Task`1 t)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<PushAndInstallPackage>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at AndroidDeviceExtensions.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<InstallSharedPlatformAsync>d__114.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<EnsureCorrectSharedRuntimes>d__111.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunAsync>d__110.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidTools.AndroidDeploySession.<RunLoggedAsync>d__108.MoveNext()
Done building project "UI.Droid.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
11>Deployment failed to Quectel Device.
========== Build: 10 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: For this error `ADB0010`, it has reported on "Errors and Warnings". You could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/errors-and-warnings/adb0010  You could try to reinstall the Android SDK.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that seeks the same, after rooting the Android OS, the response for the pm install became normal - just a 'Success' instead of that long one.

Answer (score 0):

Clear some storage space on your phone and then try again. It was worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your phone have setting `Install via USB`, and it is enabled.
You can find it right below `USB Debugging` option.